# How to read xml data into a DataSet in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Im new to .net c# programming and i need to read remote xml file into dataset and create crystal report with the dataset.

so far everything works fine except some Unicode characters showing incorrectly in crystal report viewer

so is this the correct way to load xml file which contains unicode?

```
string reportDataPath = "http://domain/test/data.xml";

DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
try
{
  reportData.ReadXml(reportDataPath);
}
catch
{

}
```

to set source

```
report = new SampleReport();
report.SetDataSource(reportData);
```

in xml file encoding set like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

**edit:-**

this is the problem im talking about. this is with sinhala unicode font

text in xml file is showing below

[image]

crystal report viewer shows below text

[image]

Regards

Comment: It sounds like you have an issue with Crystal Reports more than a problem reading XML. When you say the Unicode characters aren't showing up properly, can you give an example?

Comment: Could possibly the encoding in the file be wrong?

Comment: i've edited the question with a preview of error im talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I always try to be explicit with my encoding types so I would do it like this:

```
System.Data.DataSet reportData = new System.Data.DataSet();
System.Net.WebRequest request= System.Net.WebRequest.Create(reportDataPath);

using (System.Net.WebResponse response =   (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)) {
        reportData.ReadXml(sr);
    }
}
```

Just be aware that unicode can be encoded using different formats, UTF-8, UTF-16, etc. Mostly what you'll see is UTF-8. In .NET the encoding type Encoding.Unicode is UTF-16

Comment: thanks for the info, same output with this also and seems like its nothing to do with xml reader. its seems font has a big problem though